# Express js session id made with crypto is different when retrieved

Tags: node.js, session, express, cryptography

When trying to create a unique session id using crypto randomBytes the result of the method and what gets stored in the cookie are two different things. How can I make the data the same? Is this a safe way to make a session ID?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
...
(In sign in post, create session)
  crypto.randomBytes(128, function(ex, buf) {
    console.log(buf); // 1
    req.session.myID  = buf;
    res.render('index');
    return;
  });

(Load another page)
  console.log(req.session.myID); // 2
```

The first console.log:

> > ��`�̓<�{.Xн0=hPy'����z�ϲ�78�y���ݶ&�/�����'-��b�J�"��ܵ�ێm_���:��Y�vk�~�~r]x�/&*���KĆ��"��a��oΓ�]�1�~��-��

The second console.log:

> > 205,117,224,77,54,127,136,54,213,235,64,168,218,227,160,246,46,224,180,193,57,86,74,149,58,154,156,223,203,38,182,143,92,255,107,153,42,102,59,221,30,208,46,173,178,183,98,87,217,153,128,246,224,171,131,75,34,171,238,231,20,145,2,175,85,96,226,194,56,196,23,67,20,189,9,92,226,60,46,154,92,155,55,55,155,129,38,196,52,174,174,102,103,247,203,140,165,86,49,105,172,12,27,172,250,129,51,64,72,158,41,243,69,131,52,173,243,107,153,189,220,26,137,206,117,54,140,119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that session data is stored as JSON. Buffer instances have a `toJSON()` that is automatically called by `JSON.stringify()`. `buffer.toJSON()` returns an array of unsigned numbers representing the byte values in the Buffer.

However when the session is read back in from the session store, `JSON.parse()` does not know that that array of numbers is actually a Buffer and not something else, it just leaves it as-is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any way to keep the data in the buffer form to save space?

Comment: There is no way to keep the binary data as-is by default due to the nature of JSON. You could however write your own session store class (or fork the one you're using now) that stores the data in some other format (e.g. msgpack).